# How to find edited value and Remove it from Kendo DataSource ? (e.sender.Datasource._pristineData)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui

I want to show newly added record with existing records in kendo Grid. I have done it for newly added record. But the problem is coming while edit.

- when editing my code addes updated data with non updated data.

Before Edit

---

Name    Age    Salary
Raja    23       13000

After update  salary to 15000 from 13000

---

Name    Age    Salary
Raja    23       13000
Raja    23       15000

```
    gridData:[],                   
   onSave:function(e){
   //validation for edited or newly added data
   //then
   $.each(e.sender.dataSource._pristineData),function(inx,val){
   viewModel.gridData.push({Name:val.Name,Age:val.Age,Salary:val.Salary    })
   });
```

//in parameter map im passing new or edited value + existing data from this gridData Array.
Since **_pristineData** also have that value have to be edited data **My grid is having both edited and non edited values**

**So Please help to find edited value and non edited value. i have to seperate it and need to pass controller as two different arguments**

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all modified items from a data source by inspecting their `dirty` field.

```
var items = dataSource.data();
var updated = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   if (items[i].dirty) {
      updated.push(items[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Even though i cant remove edited item from datasource,this code is very useful to find edited value and satisfies my requirements. Thanks...